# Как проанализировать поисковые запросы устройств через Google Search Console APIs?

Tags: php, google-search, google-search-console

Работаю с Google Search Console APIs, нужно [получить анализ поисковых запросов по устройствам](http://websearch.com.ua/scrinshot/149021662144_kiss_143kb.png). Делаю всё вот так:

```
 require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
  function initializeWebmasters(){
   $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/файл сервисного аккаунта.json';
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Google Webmasters Hello");
    $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
    $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly']);
   return $client; 
  }
  $webmasters = new Google_Service_Webmasters(initializeWebmasters());

    $enddate = date("Y-m-d",time()-(3*(24*60*60)));
    $startdate = date("Y-m-d",time()-(3*(24*60*60)));

    $ar_fil_dim = new Google_Service_Webmasters_ApiDimensionFilter();
    $ar_fil_dim -> setDimension("device");
    $ar_fil_dim -> setOperator("contains");
    $ar_fil_dim -> setExpression("MOBILE");

    $ar_fil_q = new Google_Service_Webmasters_ApiDimensionFilterGroup();
    $ar_fil_q -> setFilters($ar_fil_dim);

    $webmasters1 = new Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest();
    $webmasters1->setStartDate($startdate);
    $webmasters1->setEndDate($enddate);
    $webmasters1->setSearchType("web");
    $webmasters1->setDimensions("query");
    $webmasters1->setDimensionFilterGroups($ar_fil_q);
    $webmasters1->setRowLimit(1000);

    $siteUrl = 'нужный сайт';
    $result = $webmasters->searchanalytics->query($siteUrl, $webmasters1) ;

    echo '<pre>';
      print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
```

В примере указано `"MOBILE"` для получения только с мобильных устройств (это я пробовал всё, что смог найти).

Но факт в том, что код не реагирует вообще ни на какие фильтры, и всё время отдаёт [один и тот же результат](http://websearch.com.ua/scrinshot/149021706411_kiss_145kb.png). Уже перепробовал всё, что нашёл в и-нете, но так и не могу понять, почему код не реагирует на фильтры.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так, мой простой код в котором я получаю все запросы. Обратите внимание что setDimensions идет как array, в вашем случае тоже самое нужно сделать и для остальных свойств.

```
$service = new Google_Service_Webmasters($client);
$request = new Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest();
$request->setStartDate('2017-04-01');
$request->setEndDate('2017-05-08');
$request->setDimensions(array('query'));
$result = $service->searchanalytics->query('MYDOMAIN.RU', $request);
print_r($result);
```

А вообще крайне рекомендую https://github.com/PromInc/organic-search-analytics , после 5ти минутной настройки выгружает все данные в базу, и есть веб интерфейс для удобных отчетов, сейчас сижу выгружаю 100 своих доменов и не нарадуюсь. Там же сразу набор фильтров и т.п.,  все уже включено.
http://prntscr.com/f5zgv4